# Cassandra: target machine actively refused it

Tags: windows, cassandra, database, nosql

I am trying to run Cassandra (CQL Shell) and I am receiving the following error, I have tried all the google responses to existing questions, nothing has fixed it so far.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})
```

Answer (score 1):

Before installing Apache Cassandra, JDK must be installed.

Comment: sir this is taken care before running this

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure the IP address is set correctly on your rpc_address setting in your cassandra.yaml file, on your cassandra server.
Also, you need to make sure port 9042 is open and available for incoming traffic (if your IT department is setting up servers, it is possible this port is blocked, unless otherwise specified...)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue , but may be the below 2 way's can help :

Option 1 :
In my case i haven't started the Cassandra Server and was directly trying to connect to Cassandra.
(a) Firstly start the cassandra server via cmd --> \bin>cassandra.bat -f
and then
(b) Try to connect to it's node --> \bin>cqlsh.bat -u cassandra

Option 2:
Try changing the rpc_address in your cassandra.yaml file to eihter 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
or to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost
and then again start the server from new CMD.